# ansible playbook multiple when condition with include option

Tags: ansible

I am creating playbook where i am taking input from user of which software version need to download as input and passing into tasks/main.yml

`ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt --extra-vars 'git_version=2.7.1'`

tasks/main.yml :

```
---
  - name: git
    include: ../../deploy/templates/git/git.yml
    when: git_version == "1.7.4" or
          git_version == "2.7.1" 

  - name: ant
    include: ../../deploy/templates/ant/ant.yml
    when: ant_version == "1.10.3" or
          ant_version == "1.10.4"
```

git.yml :

```
- name: Download Software
  get_url:
     url: "/Linux/git/{{ git_version }}/git-{{ git_version }}.tar.gz"
     dest: "{{ Tools }}"
     mode: 0755
```

So when i run playbook i am getting below error as syntax problem my requirement is take user input of which software he need to download and using multiple when condition with different include /import_task option to download software

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************
    ok: []

    TASK [rtt : Download Software] ********************************************************************************************
    skipping: []

    TASK [rtt : Unarchive software] *******************************************************************************************
    skipping: []

    TASK [rtt : Delete the tar file] ******************************************************************************************
    skipping: []

    TASK [rtt : Download Software] ********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: error :   
    
  
    
    TASK [rtt : Download Software] *******************************************************************************
    fatal: []: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ant_version == \"1.10.3\" or ant_version == \"1.10.4\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ant_version == \"1.10.3\" or ant_version == \"1.10.4\"): 'ant_version' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/app/home/ansible/roles/deploy/templates/ant/ant.yml': line 2, column 5, but

Comment: When you call the playbook you aren't providing a value for `ant_version`, thus the error. This could be avoided by defining `ant_version` in `defaults/main.yml` with a default value - even if it's just an empty string `''`.

Comment: yes it is true but my requriment is i need to provide only one software version at a time like either git_version or ant version so what is hapenning when i am using WHEN condition it is taking correct condition but it is not stopping immediately when condition is true it is still going for another next task  can you help the same

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my suggestion. Please see my answer below - and let me know if anything does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Ansible doesn't allow you to have `when:` conditions for undefined variables, with one exception:

```
when: variable_name is defined
```

For your purposes, it may be simpler to just set empty defaults, e.g. create `defaults/main.yml` with the following content:

```
---
ant_version: ''
git_version: ''
```

This allows the role to execute and tasks are only run when user's override the default variables (e.g. when user adds `--extra-vars 'git_version=2.7.1'` to playbook command).